# Error when starting Vireo 3 with Play 1.3.4

Tags: playframework

Vireo 3 runs with Play 1.3.4 and this issue is Play Framework related.

When I try to start Vireo 3 I get the error below in the application log. I have Vireo 3 running on a different dev server. Both that server and this one where the failure is are running Java 8. The working one is Debian and the problem one is Red Hat.

I'm starting Vireo 3 with with this:

```
[etdusr@vireo3-dev Vireo]$ play start /home/etdusr/v3-repo-a/Vireo/
```

The log shows:

```
@781jdfahf
Error loading plugin 
LoadingPluginInfo{name='org.tdl.vireo.search.impl.LucenePlayPluginImpl', index=1100, url=file:/home/etdusr/v3-repo-a/Vireo/conf/play.plugins}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run play to set up dependencies:

```
Play dependencies --sync --clearcache --%test
```